# Swift 4: Instantiating View from nib crashes without any reports

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, nib

I have custom Subclass of UIView with an associated .xib file. In the .swift file of my class inside the `required init?(_:)`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let xibView = loadViewFromNib(named: "RangeSelectorView")
    xibView.frame = self.bounds
    xibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(xibView)
}
```

I'm calling `loadViewFromNib(_:)`, which does the following:

```
func loadViewFromNib(named name: String) -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

Inside of a prototype cell of a TableViewController in my Storyboard, I have a UIView, which shall be an instance of my custom class. The code does compile without any problems but as soon as the TableViewController should appear on screen, it crashes without giving me any explicit error message.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

--Update:--

If I comment out the `required init?(_:)` and the only outlet of my .swift file (the view itself) of my custom view everything works fine so far. But then I have the problem that I can't connect Actions to repeating content, which is the case when being inside the content view of a prototype cell. This was the reason why I'm trying to source out the class to a .xib file because it will have two different gesture recognizers and some Actions triggered by them.

Comment: Check the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" list in the Identity Inspector for your views for any leftover values.

Comment: How are you setting the view inside your cell? Is your subclass `UITableViewCellContentView`?

Comment: Do you have any stray connections in your connections inspector?

Comment: @Alladinian nothing to see there

Comment: @DonMag Inside the cell's content view i have another UIView and set its class to my custom view

Comment: @Brian the content view of the cell itself has a gesture recognizer. the view inside it which is a custom view has too plus a received action. The custom view has a tap gesture recognizer and works as delegate as well for it